# insert element between text within a div element

Tags: jquery

I need to insert a break element before a piece of specific text on selecting the parent element in this case a div.
So for example.

```
<div>start finish</div>
```

And I want to add a `<br>` element before the finish text using jquery

Comment: By what criteria? Are you inserting a `<br />` in *every space* of a given text, inserting before the *last word* of a string, trying to split the text into two (approximately) equal-length lines? What you're asking is *easy*, what you *want* is (probably) more complex.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like :

```
    <div>start finish</div>

var text = $("div").text();
text = text.split(" ");
text[ text.length - 1 ] = "<br/>" + text[ text.length - 1 ];
text = text.join(" ");
$("div").html(text);
```

First extract the text from the div, next, split it on spaces, grab the last word, add a 
 before that keyword, join the array with spaces and back it to the div, as HTML.

Comment: nice but i simplified the example a bit the text within the div is a full sentence made up of pieces of info, One of which is Deliver. Deliver is static and I would like to insert the break whenever i find occurances of deliver in the sentence

Comment: Than instead of doing a split on spaces, do a split on Deliver, attach a <br/> and join the string back, my answer is only an idea how you might solve this, as the implementation is on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry overlooked our question and updating my answer

```
HTML :<div id="someid">Start Finish</div>


Javascript: $("#someid").html("start<br/>finish");
```

Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: that will add it to the end of the existing text, while i need to add it before the word finish